# Unable to get response from HTTPS Node.js application on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nodejs, https

I am running a node application on my Ubuntu laptop, that has worked just fine on other machines (Ubuntu and Mac) but for some reason it just hangs when I try and access it in a browser or Postman on this particular laptop.

It's an HTTPS application, with a self-signed certificate, but on all the other machines it has previously run on that is not a problem - I just click "allow" when asked if I trust the site or not.

As soon as I kill the node app, the browser reacts with an error, so it just seems like something is getting caught waiting and my requests never get through.

Other similar threads suggest to use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, but that's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simply to upgrade my version of Node.js - I got the latest version and it all works okay, as on the other machines. At least I got a tumbleweed badge of out it anyway ;-)